# How to center text on top of image in HTML

Tags: html, image, center

After searching a lot of guides I have managed to do this: http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/491/1i7.png but when using it on other website the text is misplaced (you can see that at http://www.indiedb.com/games/celosia). Here is the code I've used:

```
<IMG SRC="http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/2261/vvpp.png">
<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:10px; left:30px; width:900px; height:25px">
<CENTER><FONT SIZE="+1" COLOR="white">Celosia - the gothic memory card game is a game for everyone, new to this genre or veterans, you will truly enjoy the dark atmosphere and awesome music. Help a goddess, travel around the world and unveil a big mystery or test your skills in the Time attack or Boss modes in over 50 levels. Celosia is currently in Alpha stage so everything you see is subject to changes. You can also follow the official Facebook or Twitter page for updates and news.</FONT></CENTER>
</DIV>
```

Comment: thebest would be I think to define the div with your text and use your image as the background image of the div (in CSS).

Answer (score 0):

```
<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:10px; left:30px; width:900px; height:25px;background-url:http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/2261/vvpp.png;">
<CENTER><FONT SIZE="+1" COLOR="white">Celosia - the gothic memory card game is a game for        everyone, new to this genre or veterans, you will truly enjoy the dark atmosphere and awesome     music. Help a goddess, travel around the world and unveil a big mystery or test your skills in     the Time attack or Boss modes in over 50 levels. Celosia is currently in Alpha stage so     everything you see is subject to changes. You can also follow the official Facebook or Twitter     page for updates and news.</FONT></CENTER>
</DIV>
```

UPDATE:

Try this instead. http://jsfiddle.net/astephenb/mBu4h/

Comment: I have tested this and it doesn't show any image or text. Also the text position is the same, are you sure it will be centered when it currently isn't?